# MacOSX build not running on older version

Tags: xcode, osx-mavericks, osx-yosemite, osx-mountain-lion, osx-snow-leopard

I am facing a strange issue on 10.8. My client is reporting that build isn't working on 10.8. I have tested the build on 2 systems both systems have 10.11 installed.

in 10.8 log its saying

```
 Library not loaded: @rpath/libfmod.dylib
 reason: image not found
```

I have added "@executable_path" in Runtime Search Path.
In Copy files build phase i have added libfmod.dylib and its destination is Executables

In my personal opinion if the problem is with run path then it shouldn't run on my machine either.

Another thing i have noticed is both machines have diffrent "Referenced From" path. my client crash log for osx10.8 shows

```
/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/.MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/My App
```

while my log shows

```
/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp
```

could this be a problem?

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

here is the result of running otool -l command on dylib

```
    Load command 3
          cmd LC_ID_DYLIB
      cmdsize 48
         name @rpath/libfmod.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 1 Thu Jan  1 05:00:01 1970
      current version 1.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 4
     cmd LC_SYMTAB
 cmdsize 24
  symoff 1320816
   nsyms 1233
  stroff 1341592
 strsize 38776
Load command 5
            cmd LC_DYSYMTAB
        cmdsize 80
      ilocalsym 0
      nlocalsym 1
     iextdefsym 1
     nextdefsym 1107
      iundefsym 1108
      nundefsym 125
         tocoff 0
           ntoc 0
      modtaboff 0
        nmodtab 0
   extrefsymoff 0
    nextrefsyms 0
 indirectsymoff 1340592
  nindirectsyms 250
      extreloff 1340544
        nextrel 6
      locreloff 1302528
        nlocrel 1672
Load command 6
     cmd LC_UUID
 cmdsize 24
    uuid 44E30C32-DE34-37CF-BD39-3F67491607C4
Load command 7
      cmd LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX
  cmdsize 16
  version 10.5
      sdk 10.11
Load command 8
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 88
         name /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 05:00:02 1970
      current version 157.0.0
compatibility version 2.0.0
Load command 9
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 96
         name /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioUnit.framework/Versions/A/AudioUnit (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 05:00:02 1970
      current version 1.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 10
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 96
         name /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Versions/A/CoreAudio (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 05:00:02 1970
      current version 1.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 11
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 56
         name /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 05:00:02 1970
      current version 104.1.0
compatibility version 7.0.0
Load command 12
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 56
         name /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 05:00:02 1970
      current version 1225.1.1
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 13
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 56
         name /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 05:00:02 1970
      current version 955.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 14
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 104
         name /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 05:00:02 1970
      current version 1253.0.0
compatibility version 150.0.0
Load command 15
      cmd LC_FUNCTION_STARTS
  cmdsize 16
  dataoff 1315904
 datasize 4912
Load command 16
      cmd LC_DATA_IN_CODE
  cmdsize 16
  dataoff 1320816
 datasize 0
```

**Edit otool -l results for app**

```
Load command 0
      cmd LC_SEGMENT_64
  cmdsize 72
  segname __PAGEZERO
   vmaddr 0x0000000000000000
   vmsize 0x0000000100000000
  fileoff 0
 filesize 0
  maxprot 0x00000000
 initprot 0x00000000
   nsects 0
    flags 0x0
Load command 1
      cmd LC_SEGMENT_64
  cmdsize 952
  segname __TEXT
   vmaddr 0x0000000100000000
   vmsize 0x00000000001fe000
  fileoff 0
 filesize 2088960
  maxprot 0x00000007
 initprot 0x00000005
   nsects 11
    flags 0x0
Section
  sectname __text
   segname __TEXT
      addr 0x0000000100001ba0
      size 0x0000000000175017
    offset 7072
     align 2^4 (16)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x80000400
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __stubs
   segname __TEXT
      addr 0x0000000100176bb8
      size 0x00000000000033ae
    offset 1534904
     align 2^1 (2)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x80000408
 reserved1 0 (index into indirect symbol table)
 reserved2 6 (size of stubs)
Section
  sectname __stub_helper
   segname __TEXT
      addr 0x0000000100179f68
      size 0x0000000000000c90
    offset 1548136
     align 2^2 (4)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x80000400
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __const
   segname __TEXT
      addr 0x000000010017ac00
      size 0x0000000000005048
    offset 1551360
     align 2^5 (32)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __gcc_except_tab
   segname __TEXT
      addr 0x000000010017fc48
      size 0x00000000000163a0
    offset 1571912
     align 2^2 (4)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __cstring
   segname __TEXT
      addr 0x0000000100195fe8
      size 0x000000000000c783
    offset 1662952
     align 2^3 (8)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000002
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __objc_classname
   segname __TEXT
      addr 0x00000001001a276b
      size 0x0000000000000081
    offset 1714027
     align 2^0 (1)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000002
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __objc_methname
   segname __TEXT
      addr 0x00000001001a27ec
      size 0x0000000000001505
    offset 1714156
     align 2^0 (1)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000002
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __objc_methtype
   segname __TEXT
      addr 0x00000001001a3cf1
      size 0x0000000000001609
    offset 1719537
     align 2^0 (1)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000002
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __unwind_info
   segname __TEXT
      addr 0x00000001001a52fc
      size 0x0000000000006e20
    offset 1725180
     align 2^2 (4)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __eh_frame
   segname __TEXT
      addr 0x00000001001ac120
      size 0x0000000000051ec8
    offset 1753376
     align 2^3 (8)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Load command 2
      cmd LC_SEGMENT_64
  cmdsize 1512
  segname __DATA
   vmaddr 0x00000001001fe000
   vmsize 0x0000000000028000
  fileoff 2088960
 filesize 126976
  maxprot 0x00000007
 initprot 0x00000003
   nsects 18
    flags 0x0
Section
  sectname __nl_symbol_ptr
   segname __DATA
      addr 0x00000001001fe000
      size 0x0000000000000010
    offset 2088960
     align 2^3 (8)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000006
 reserved1 2205 (index into indirect symbol table)
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __got
   segname __DATA
      addr 0x00000001001fe010
      size 0x0000000000000240
    offset 2088976
     align 2^3 (8)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000006
 reserved1 2207 (index into indirect symbol table)
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __la_symbol_ptr
   segname __DATA
      addr 0x00000001001fe250
      size 0x00000000000044e8
    offset 2089552
     align 2^3 (8)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000007
 reserved1 2279 (index into indirect symbol table)
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __mod_init_func
   segname __DATA
      addr 0x0000000100202738
      size 0x0000000000000470
    offset 2107192
     align 2^3 (8)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000009
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __const
   segname __DATA
      addr 0x0000000100202bc0
      size 0x0000000000013400
    offset 2108352
     align 2^5 (32)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __cfstring
   segname __DATA
      addr 0x0000000100215fc0
      size 0x0000000000000480
    offset 2187200
     align 2^3 (8)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __objc_classlist
   segname __DATA
      addr 0x0000000100216440
      size 0x0000000000000030
    offset 2188352
     align 2^3 (8)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x10000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __objc_protolist
   segname __DATA
      addr 0x0000000100216470
      size 0x0000000000000018
    offset 2188400
     align 2^3 (8)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __objc_imageinfo
   segname __DATA
      addr 0x0000000100216488
      size 0x0000000000000008
    offset 2188424
     align 2^2 (4)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __objc_const
   segname __DATA
      addr 0x0000000100216490
      size 0x0000000000001da0
    offset 2188432
     align 2^3 (8)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __objc_selrefs
   segname __DATA
      addr 0x0000000100218230
      size 0x00000000000005a0
    offset 2196016
     align 2^3 (8)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x10000005
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __objc_classrefs
   segname __DATA
      addr 0x00000001002187d0
      size 0x0000000000000128
    offset 2197456
     align 2^3 (8)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x10000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __objc_superrefs
   segname __DATA
      addr 0x00000001002188f8
      size 0x0000000000000028
    offset 2197752
     align 2^3 (8)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x10000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __objc_ivar
   segname __DATA
      addr 0x0000000100218920
      size 0x0000000000000088
    offset 2197792
     align 2^3 (8)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __objc_data
   segname __DATA
      addr 0x00000001002189a8
      size 0x00000000000001e0
    offset 2197928
     align 2^3 (8)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __data
   segname __DATA
      addr 0x0000000100218b90
      size 0x0000000000003500
    offset 2198416
     align 2^4 (16)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __common
   segname __DATA
      addr 0x000000010021c0a0
      size 0x0000000000002cd0
    offset 0
     align 2^5 (32)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000001
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __bss
   segname __DATA
      addr 0x000000010021ed80
      size 0x0000000000006d7f
    offset 0
     align 2^5 (32)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000001
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Load command 3
      cmd LC_SEGMENT_64
  cmdsize 72
  segname __LINKEDIT
   vmaddr 0x0000000100226000
   vmsize 0x000000000005bd20
  fileoff 2215936
 filesize 376096
  maxprot 0x00000007
 initprot 0x00000001
   nsects 0
    flags 0x0
Load command 4
            cmd LC_DYLD_INFO_ONLY
        cmdsize 48
     rebase_off 2215936
    rebase_size 1848
       bind_off 2217784
      bind_size 3592
  weak_bind_off 2221376
 weak_bind_size 3248
  lazy_bind_off 2224624
 lazy_bind_size 8704
     export_off 2233328
    export_size 173048
Load command 5
     cmd LC_SYMTAB
 cmdsize 24
  symoff 2416712
   nsyms 2350
  stroff 2472248
 strsize 119784
Load command 6
            cmd LC_DYSYMTAB
        cmdsize 80
      ilocalsym 0
      nlocalsym 1881
     iextdefsym 1881
     nextdefsym 71
      iundefsym 1952
      nundefsym 398
         tocoff 0
           ntoc 0
      modtaboff 0
        nmodtab 0
   extrefsymoff 0
    nextrefsyms 0
 indirectsymoff 2454312
  nindirectsyms 4484
      extreloff 0
        nextrel 0
      locreloff 0
        nlocrel 0
Load command 7
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLINKER
      cmdsize 32
         name /usr/lib/dyld (offset 12)
Load command 8
     cmd LC_UUID
 cmdsize 24
    uuid BD90987E-8A90-3083-B629-E9F378270B47
Load command 9
      cmd LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX
  cmdsize 16
  version 10.8
      sdk 10.8
Load command 10
      cmd LC_SOURCE_VERSION
  cmdsize 16
  version 0.0
Load command 11
       cmd LC_MAIN
   cmdsize 24
  entryoff 288778
 stacksize 0
Load command 12
          cmd LC_LOAD_WEAK_DYLIB
      cmdsize 112
         name /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 05:00:02 1970
      current version 45.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 13
          cmd LC_LOAD_WEAK_DYLIB
      cmdsize 152
         name /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 05:00:02 1970
      current version 600.0.0
compatibility version 64.0.0
Load command 14
          cmd LC_LOAD_WEAK_DYLIB
      cmdsize 88
         name /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 05:00:02 1970
      current version 1.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 15
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 96
         name /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/Versions/A/CoreMedia (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 05:00:02 1970
      current version 1.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 16
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 104
         name /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Versions/A/AVFoundation (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 05:00:02 1970
      current version 2.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 17
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 48
         name @rpath/libfmod.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 05:00:02 1970
      current version 1.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 18
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 88
         name /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 05:00:02 1970
      current version 1187.37.0
compatibility version 45.0.0
Load command 19
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 104
         name /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 05:00:02 1970
      current version 1.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 20
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 88
         name /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 05:00:02 1970
      current version 19.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 21
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 104
         name /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 05:00:02 1970
      current version 744.18.0
compatibility version 150.0.0
Load command 22
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 96
         name /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 05:00:02 1970
      current version 945.16.0
compatibility version 300.0.0
Load command 23
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 88
         name /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenAL.framework/Versions/A/OpenAL (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 05:00:02 1970
      current version 1.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 24
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 88
         name /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 05:00:02 1970
      current version 1.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 25
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 96
         name /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 05:00:02 1970
      current version 1.8.0
compatibility version 1.2.0
Load command 26
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 56
         name /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 05:00:02 1970
      current version 10.8.0
compatibility version 10.0.0
Load command 27
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 48
         name /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 05:00:02 1970
      current version 1.2.5
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 28
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 56
         name /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 05:00:02 1970
      current version 56.0.0
compatibility version 7.0.0
Load command 29
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 56
         name /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 05:00:02 1970
      current version 169.3.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 30
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 96
         name /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 05:00:02 1970
      current version 1.8.0
compatibility version 1.2.0
Load command 31
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 56
         name /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 05:00:02 1970
      current version 228.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 32
          cmd LC_RPATH
      cmdsize 32
         path @executable_path (offset 12)
Load command 33
      cmd LC_FUNCTION_STARTS
  cmdsize 16
  dataoff 2406376
 datasize 10336
Load command 34
      cmd LC_DATA_IN_CODE
  cmdsize 16
  dataoff 2416712
 datasize 0
```

Comment: Is the library actually there inside the package?  Have you verified that the binary that loads that library really is trying to load it from @executable_path by using "otool -l" on the command-line?  Are you copying the project across in a way that properly preserves resource forks?  (I ask because of that weird path; are you sure it isn't ._MyApp.app?)

Comment: I am sure its .MyApp.app. and yes library is inside the package. otherwise it wouldn't run on my machines. Package is located inside Contents/MacOS directory

Comment: ottool -l gives following result

Load command 17
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 48
         name @rpath/libfmod.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 05:00:02 1970
      current version 1.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0

and i am not copying the project i am just copying app file. there is no issue with copying because copied file runs well on OS X 10.10 and above

Comment: Now do the same thing on the library, and see if Load command 8 (LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX) is set sufficiently low that the library itself can actually load on 10.9 and earlier.

Comment: LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX is set to 10.5 i am posting complete result in edit

Comment: The 'referenced from' (Contents/Resources/.MyApp.app/...) path looks strange to me, does that path exist in your app bundle? Keep in mind you won't be able to see it in finder due the the dot prefix (use terminal).